# Excel formula for calculating sum of 52 cells out of possible 104 where blank cells exist

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to find a formula for Microsoft Excel that will allow me to calculate the sum of 52 weeks.

The Excel sheet is set up with 104 weeks of data, some of which weeks have blank cell. I am trying to calculate the sum of the newest 52 weeks which have data. The Excel sheet has multiple lines of data and therefore no two lines are the same (i.e. blanks in different places).

I know its complex, and I thought I was good at Excel but this has stumped everyone I know.

Comment: Could you show us your attempt?

Comment: Show us also your worksheet.

Comment: You should provide a sample here and it will more clearly to help you.

Comment: More details are needed. Much like this other question you [recently posted](https://superuser.com/q/1750734/167207) showing examples of what you have tried and done so far can help the community help you solve this issue. But without actual details, this is basically a script coding request which is not what this site is about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some helper columns to achieve what you are asking. Making some assumptions since the question does not include any sample data. Here, I'm assuming your data appear like columns A and B below, where A is your week (sorted by descending) and column B is your value that you're trying to SUM.

*Also, so that I can fit all data into a single screenshot, I'm summing just the most recent 10 weeks of populated data. Adjust the second formula as necessary.*

**First Helper Column (Column C)**: Place a 0 (zero) as your column header, and insert the following COUNTA formula in cell C2. This formula counts the number of non-blank cells starting from Cell B2 to current row. Drag it down.

```
    =COUNTA($B$2:B2)
```

**Second Helper Column (Column D)**: Insert the following IF(AND) formula in cell D2. This will code that row as "yes" if the prior column's value equals the row above plus 1, AND, if that value is less than 11. Adjust to 53 in your case. Drag it down.

```
    =IF(AND(C1+1=C2,C2<11),"yes","no")
```

**Lastly**, use the following SUMIFS formula, which is found in cell G2, and sums the values where helper D = "yes".

```
    =SUMIFS(B:B,D:D,"yes")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula:

```
=LET(  List,  FILTERXML("<group><element>"&TEXTJOIN("</element><element>",TRUE,A1:A104)&"</element></group>","/*/*"),

        IF(COUNT(List)<52,"Not enough weeks",SUM(INDEX(List,SEQUENCE(52,1,COUNT(List),-1),1)))
      )
```

It uses `TEXTJOIN()` to make a string of the 104 values (A1:A104 here, adjust as needed) with the important feature being that it is dropping all the blank cells so only value cells are retained. It uses as a delimiter the HTML tag sequence that `FILTERXML()` will need between elements of the group of values. This cuts out a `SUBSTITUTE()` step.

The string is then adjusted at its front and back to be acceptable to `FILTERXML()` and that function returns the values from being a single string to being an array of discrete values, in the order they appeared originally. But all empty cells have been dropped from the array.

You want the newest 52 values, so first there is a check to see if there are that many at all, returning "Not enough values" if the count is less than 52.

If >=52, then the next step reverses their original order and selects the first 52 of those. These are then summed.

Because the `FILTERXML()` step is a long patch of formula, it uses `LET()` to make things more immediately readable. Not necessary, but it seems worthwhile.

The important elements are finding just the "not-blank" cells to use and then selecting the last 52 of them.

The following would work as well and be far shorter with the thought that it would also never run into the length limitations of "internal to formulas" strings like `FILTERXML()` will. `FILTERXML()` has two advantages though, one being that it can pull numbered elements for you and the other can have a more complicated HTML string built, without much trouble, so as to give you two or more columns of data rather than just a single set.

```
=LET(  List,  FILTER(A1:A104,A1:A104<>0),

        IF(COUNT(List)<52,"Not enough weeks",SUM(INDEX(List,SEQUENCE(52,1,COUNT(List),-1),1)))
      )
```

There would be other approaches to the reversal of the list as well. One would be to use the `FILTERXML()` approach and do a "from:to" with the records with the record numbers being based upon the `COUNT(List)` value so it takes the last 52. One does that in the string called the "XPath" in the `FILTERXML()` function, the "/*/*" at the end of it in the first formula above. It needs to look like:

```
"/*/*[last]" or "/*/*[43]"
```

but one can build the string using formula, so one would use the first of those two, but instead of the second, one might use:

```
"/*/*["  &  (COUNT(List) - 52 + 1) &  "]"
```

to get the first to use. Looks a nightmare, but it's pretty clear after doing it a time or two. Not necessary for your question, but an extension of what you might do with future uses. For instance, one could extract a record like so for comparison in an `IF()`. Could be used in a Conditional Format for your problem to change maybe a background color to indicate the sum covers parts of two years, not just one. Although there'd be easier ways to test that given the uncomplicated nature of your data!