# Unsure how to combine two Excel formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am having trouble combining two Excel formulas.

I have tried and tried and can get one part to work then another doesn't. I have broken down so that each formula works it its own right, but I need them to read if cell `O426="Day"`, then if `N426=Rental`, then `N426=Sale` then…

Formula 1:

```
=if(O426="Day",IF((MAX(AR426:BQ426))<=CQ4,sum(Y426-sum(CN426:CP426))))
```

Formula 2:

```
=iferror(IF(N426="Rental",Sum(MAX(MIN(AC426,CQ4)-MAX(AB426,CQ3)+1,0*AE426),if(N426="SAle",if((MAX(AR426:BC426))<=CQ4,sum(Y426-sum(CN426-cp426)),0))),0)
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add an attempt you made to do this? If the community sees what you tried they would be in a better position to help you.

Comment: What happened with your various attempts? Errors? Failures?

Comment: Do you try the IFS function?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have both cell calculated you could use a logical function with a cascaded if

```
if (and(o426="D",n426="R"),  {calc d-r value}, if(and(o426="D",n426="S"),
{calc d-s value},  ¨calc all other conditions))
```

The outer if tests for Day Rental, the false side action of it start an inner if that test for Day-Sale and the false side catches all other conditions.

This combination can be extended to quite complex logic